# Where can I find the time picker view of the native alarm clock app of android?

Tags: android, view, geometry, clock, alarm

I am looking for the circle shaped view, which allows you to pick the hour and after that the minutes for the alarm. Both, the possible numbers are distributed in a circle.

I couldnt find that view in the native API, is there a chance to use this view type ? Or do I have to create one on my own ?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I am looking for this:

[image: http://s1.directupload.net/images/140123/iwbb4d3y.png]

Comment: The alarm clock app is open source here
https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_alarmclock

Comment: Thx but its not what I am looking for. See above.

Comment: try this for source code looks circular from the refrences..
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/datetimepicker/+/master/src/com/android/datetimepicker

particluarly this package
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/datetimepicker/+/master/src/com/android/datetimepicker/time/

Comment: This isnt the same but if need be
http://androiddev.orkitra.com/?p=79555

Answer (score 4):

Here are a few libraries:

1. https://github.com/flavienlaurent/datetimepicker
2. https://github.com/CiTuX/datetimepicker
3. https://github.com/Mirkoddd/GoogleDateTimePickers

Or you can look at the sourcecode Google wrote: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/datetimepicker/+/master/src/com/android/datetimepicker/time/TimePickerDialog.java

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for `android.widget.TimePicker` with the attribute

```
android:timePickerMode="clock"
```

EDIT: It comes with the API 23

Answer (score 0):

It is called a timepickerdialog, it should be available if you are using android studio or eclipse.